# Let the system $Ax=b$ be incompatible. Prove that $C^kx=0, C=[A,b]$ is determined for all $k\in \Bbb{N}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let $A \in \Bbb{R}^{n \times (n-1) }$ be of rank $n-1$, let $b\in \Bbb{R}^n$.

Let the system $Ax=b$ be incompatible.

Prove that $C^kx=0, C=[A,b]$ is determined for all $k\in \Bbb{N}$.

I can't use properties of the determinant here, and I kind of can see why this is true, but I have no idea on how to start a proof, hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Think about the rank of $C$. That is, what is the dimension of the column space of $C$.

Comment: The rank of C could be $n-1$ or $n$ right? I feel it should be $n$, but I don't understand why: how do I know that adding a non-zero column (matrix $b$) will add a non linearly dependent one, bumping the rank up to $n$?

Comment: If the rank of $C$ were $n-1$, then its columns would be linearly dependent. Write out what that means and solve the resulting equation for the vector $b$. Now look at your assumptions.

Comment: Oh I think I get why $Rank(C)=n$. If it was $n-1$ then Ax=b would be compatible right?

Then Cx=0 is determined, and I do the rest by induction?

Comment: That's a good way to do this. Details need to be filled in of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption $rank(A) = n-1$  implies that the columns $a_1, \dots, a_{n-1}$ of $A$ are linearly independent. **Then since $Ax = b$ is incompatible, the vectors $a_1, \dots, a_{n-1},b$ are also linearly independent.**

Otherwise one could find numbers $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$, not all zero, such that 
$$
\alpha_1 a_1 + \dots \alpha_{n-1}a_{n-1} + \alpha_n b = 0
$$
or in matrix notation $A \tilde \alpha = - \alpha_n b$, where $\tilde \alpha = (\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{n-1})^T$.

Then $\alpha_n$ cannot be zero since the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent. But if $\alpha_n \ne 0$, the system $Ax = b$ has the solution $x = -\alpha_n^{-1} \tilde \alpha$, so that is also impossible.

Consequently the matrix $C = [A,b]$ has rank $n$ and is invertible. It follows that all powers $C^k$ are also invertible and the systems $C^kx = 0$ all have only the trivial solution $x = 0$.